# remote connect or run IIS with public ip to a Virtualbox which is inside EC2

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, vmware, virtualbox

I am running a windows in oracle virtualbox and my virtualbox is inside Amazon EC2. Is it possible to access my IIS server which is inside virtualbox using a public IP address. I have been trying all these time. I created two network interfaces and assigned one to my EC2 and the other one to Virtual box. but it's not assigning a IP and it says unidentified network. Is it possible to do this or not?